# Reading files from application memory

Tags: android, string, file

I'm trying to get some strings which I have saved in my app and print them. For some reason my app crashes. Could you help me? :)

```
ListView list;
String[] listC, filenames;
String entry;
int files, i;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pastbets);

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    listC = new String[filenames.length/2];
    Prepare();

    ArrayAdapter<String> filenameAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listC);
    list.setAdapter(filenameAdapter);
}

private void Prepare() {
    filenames = getApplicationContext().fileList();
    files = filenames.length/2;
    for(i=0; i<files; i++) {
        entry = openFile(filenames[2*i])+" - "+openFile(filenames[2*i+1]);
        listC[i] = entry;
    }
}
```

I think that the 'openFile' function is ok, though...

```
private String openFile(String selectFile) {
    String file = "";
    FileInputStream fis;

    try {
        fis = openFileInput(selectFile);
        byte[] input = new byte[fis.available()];
        while(fis.read(input) != -1){
            file += new String(input);
        }
        fis.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return file;
}
```

Comment: You are using `filenames` without setting it to anything.

Answer (score 0):

application is crashing because `filenames` Array is not initialized before using it so call `Prepare()` method before initializing `listC` array as:

```
 list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
 Prepare();
 listC = new String[filenames.length/2];
```